# Increment output for this Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick-convert

Can I change this script so that I get an increment output file?
Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Collect all files in the files array
files=( *jpg )
## How many should be done at once
batch=5
## Read the array in batches of $batch
for (( i=0; $i<${#files[@]}; i+=$batch ))
do   
## Convert this batch   
convert -delay 10 -morph 10 "${files[@]:$i:$batch}" $i.jpg
done
```

For now the output is like this:

```
0-0.jpg
1-3.jpg
1-30.jpg
12-3.jpg
```

and unsortable.

Comment: How should the desired output look like, exactly?

Comment: Simply count up with Zeros. 00001.jpg 00002.jpg ... The Files are to create a Video file.

Comment: If you jsut want to format with leading zeros then use format. `echo $(printf %04d 10).jpg`. Please extend your question with desired in AND output.

Comment: what about a later sort with 'ls --sort=time -rl'?

Comment: imo the naming convention comes from convert, I got also weird file names in case of pdf converting. The only way I found was a second bash script to change generated file names to the style I need

Comment: a subsequent renaming would be an option. How can i rename a file like this 10-2.jpg to 10-02.jpg or 9-4.jpg to 09-04.jpg?

Comment: I'm not sure about the desired sequence but with Bash 3.0+ you can try something like :     `for i in {00..30..5}; do echo "file-$i.jpg"; done`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should rename your files in order of creation.

```
#!/bin/bash

# modify the ls statement to include files you need
files=(`ls --sort=time -r *.jpg`)

for (( i=0; $i<${#files[@]}; i+=1 ))
do
 numStr=`printf "%05d\n" $i`
 # debug output
 echo "${files[i]} --> $numStr"
 mv "${files[i]}" "${numStr}.jpg"
done
```

Comment: Almost perfect, but unfortunately directories and the script itself be renamed.

Comment: ok, with this line it works with jpg.    files=(`ls --sort=time -r` *.jpg)